# Can not get Latitude and Longitude

Tags: java, android, location

I'm trying to get location information. I need the longitude and latitude.

I'm using my phone to run and debug. Its 4.4.2.

My AndroidManifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.peylx.brstpcu.voteapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Activity

```
package com.peylx.brstpcu.voteapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.audiofx.BassBoost;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude = " + Double.toString(latitude) + "Longitude = " + Double.toString(longitude),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
            }
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);

                return;
            }
        } else {
            configureButton();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    configureButton();
                return;
        }

    }

    private void configureButton(){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);

    }
}
```

When I try to debug my program, it doesn't go `onLocationChanged()` method. So I can't get `Toast` message.

What can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you set your listener?

Comment: I wanna get all of these at activity start. So thats why im added configureButton() method to onCreate section

Comment: You are asking for  button listener right ? if you are asking locationListener i already used it at configureButton method

Comment: You're instantiating a listener but you're doing nothing with it so why do you think you should receive location updates? Take a look at `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` method

Comment: i tryed with button too

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

1) Implement OnMyLocationChangeListener in your HomeActivity.

2) Copy foll. method -

```
private Location getMyLocation() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        // if Location wasn't found
        if (myLocation == null) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            // Use the provider to get the last known location
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            double lat1 = myLocation.getLatitude();
            double lng1 = myLocation.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Latitude = " + lat1 + "Longitude = " + lng1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return myLocation;
    }
```

3) Call getMyLocation() method in onCreate()

It works for me :)

**Note :** OnMyLocationChangeListener is Deprecated (please check google documentation)

Comment: Am i should add some dependencies for use this method ?

Comment: i cant implements OnMyLocationListener. What about LocationListener ? sorry im newbie a bit

Comment: If you are using Android Studio then add dependency as -       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:*.*.*'   where, * indicates latest version of the library. and Then implement  OnMyLocationChangeListener in activity. U can use both LocationListener interface or  OnMyLocationChangeListener interface as per ua choice. Please refer - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener  for google play services.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Already my code is running now but im gonna try this too

Answer (score 0):

First of all your activity should implement LocationListener

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{


private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitude = " + Double.toString(latitude) + "Longitude = " + Double.toString(longitude),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            }, 10);

            return;
        }
    } else {
        configureButton();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                configureButton();
            return;
    }

}

private void configureButton(){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);

    }
}
```